# What bad things happens to me if I don't url-encode backslashes in query calls?

Tags: php, url, url-encoding

I know php's `http_build_query()` url-encodes backslash-characters in the query string. I also know that the backslash is a reserved character, making this the desired behavior for that function. I have seen people I respect as programmers use unencoded backslashes in their query strings, and have been wanting to do the same to make my urls look a little nicer. What bad things (if any) do I have to expect when refraining from url-encoding my backslashes?

The reason I even started to think about breaking the url-encoding conventions is the fact that google uses plusses in their query strings. Does anyone know what bad things happen to THEM for doing that?

The problem I am ultimately trying to solve is to somehow delimit my `?q=MVC` calls with a humanly legible, url-safe character, without having to set more than one query variable.

Comment: Using `+` is a very common way to send a list of words in a query string. I will quote RFC 1738: *Scheme names consist of a sequence of characters. The lower case letters "a"--"z", digits, and the characters plus ("+"), period ("."), and hyphen ("-") are allowed.*

Comment: Do you really mean backslash (\\) and not slash (/)?

Comment: @unor I think you might be right, they were probably using slashes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) is pretty clear about this:

> > query       = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
> >
> > The characters slash ("/") and question mark ("?") may represent data
> >        within the query component. Beware that some older, erroneous
> >        implementations may not handle such data correctly...

So it's fine to use slashes in the query part (unless you have to deal with implementations that were "older" back in 2005).

Comment: I have read that part. I guess what I am wondering is: Since it works to not encode backslashes, what can I expect to happen if I don't?

Comment: Isn't DudeOnRock asking for backslashes (\\)?

Comment: @unor: yeah, right. I guess I'd better delete that to avoid confusion.

Comment: But the answer is accepted, so maybe he meant slashes anyway.

Comment: @unor: anyways, I can't delete it. Let the OP decide.